# Panframe - 360 Video Player Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, playback, 360-virtual-reality

I built a **360 video player** using **Panframe SDK** and I'm facing a strange problem.

When I start the app and the video start playing.

> It never start from the video center point unless I'm in a specific
>   direction.
>
> If I changed my sitting direction then start the app , It starts from
>   totally different point every time.

I just want to make the center of the video always the start point even if I changed my direction, Just like other **360 video players**.

Thanks a lot guys for your help in advance :)

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bonatti for the clarification ..  I'm already familiar with this, But the question is really pretty hard to clarify more .. This  explains my problem as much as I could.

Comment: Well, this is a long shot, but have you checked [resetView](http://www.panframe.com/sdk/ios/api/1.9.8/Classes/PFView.html)

Comment: Did you check the native Code of Google ?   https://developers.google.com/vr/android/

Comment: It's great ,, But unfortunately I can't see it in the Android reference .. Or even alternative to resetView . Thanks a lot @Bonatti

Comment: @Cliff I took a look before at it but I found Panframe SDK is a little more powerful .. Maybe I'm mistaken ..!

Comment: @NapsterAhmed dunno man just keep it in the box :)